# How to find the integration limits of a surface integral involving $z=x+y^2$, $z<0$ and $x>-1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the surface integral of a vector function **u** (whose definition is irrelevant to this problem) over the surface $$z=x+y^2 $$
with $z<0$ and  $x>-1$.

Initially I put $$x+y^2<0 $$
$$-\sqrt{-x}<y<\sqrt{-x} $$
$$-1<x<0 $$
which gave $$\int\int_S\bf{u} \cdot{\bf{n}}\textit{dS}=\int_{x=-1}^{x=0}\int_{y=-\sqrt{-x}}^{y=\sqrt{-x}}\bf{u} \cdot{\frac{\partial r}{\partial \textit{x}}}\times\frac{\partial r}{\partial \textit{y}}\textit{dydx} $$
and yielded the correct answer.

But I then tried to reverse the order of integration for $x$ and $y$, so again 
$$x+y^2<0$$
$$-1<x<-y^2$$
but now I'm struggling to find the integration limits for $y$ (setting $x$ to zero also makes no sense in this case).

Is there a way to find such limits (for $y$) without having to plot the whole 3d graph for $z=x+y^2$?

Comment: Since (in the $z=0$ plane) $x=-1$ and $x=-y^2$ meets at $(-1,-1,0)$ and $(-1,1,0)$ then the limits for $y$ are $y=-1$ and $y=1$.

Comment: Thanks. So we always set the given inequalities to equalities to obtain these limits?